# Calling interstitial iAd works only one time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, iad

I have spritekit game, Ad is preloaded on each start of game with `[UIViewController prepareInterstitialAds];` And after gameover it should display ad with `[self.view.window.rootViewController requestInterstitialAdPresentation];` and it's works okay, but only first time. The ad's shows only one time. After failing another game, ad do not show though preload. Any suggestions?

Comment: Be sure that your presentation policy is set to manual. self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual; Also, set your instance of ADInterstitialAd to nil and create a new instance before requesting a new interstitial. If you could post more of your code that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have it set up to where it runs

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
```

each time the game ends?

Comment: First it's called this requestInterstitialAdPresentation and then transition to another skscene. First time it works, shows Ad and after close skscene is presented.

Comment: it could be because it's test iad  in sandbox? Should that do not occur on live iad netowrk?

Answer (score 1):

See the answer by gj15987 here...
[requestInterstitialAdPresentation Works only one Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338216/requestinterstitialadpresentation-works-only-one-time?rq=1)

He says there's a two minute block out period.  I tried it and found it took 3min 20sec to allow another ad for me.  I have fill rate set to 100% in the Developer section of Settings.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc :

"The second major difference between a banner view and an full-screen advertisement is that the full-screen advertisement does not cycle through new content. An full-screen ad object loads a single advertisement; once that content expires, your app must release the ad object. Each time your app needs to show a new advertisement, it must explicitly create a new ad object."

straight from the horse's mouth :

[iAd Programming Guide : Full-Screen Advertisements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH5-SW1)

Comment: That documentation is out of date and uses deprecated methods, such as [interstitial presentFromViewController:self]; It also says interstitials are only available to iPad, so it's pretty counter-intuitive I found.