# requestInterstitialAdPresentation Works only one Time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iad

I am wondering why 
`[self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];` 
 works only one time. I mean that I binded this call into UIButton, First time I run my app, and click this button the ad appear correctly but, when I close ad and trying to call again for another ad, simply ad do not appear though nslog said that function was called. On start app I preload ad with 
 `[UIViewController prepareInterstitialAds];`

Comment: it could be because it's test iad  in sandbox? Should that do not occur on live iad netowrk?

Comment: In my App requestInterstitialAdPresentation works fine again after clicking on a banner view

Comment: @Stefan I see the same as you. Wait roughly 2 minutes or touch a banner.

Answer (score 3):

I've just come across this and it seems there's a time out to stop people spamming users with adverts after every other segue.

I don't know if it can vary, but I've just tried it myself and the time out was roughly 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try at this:

The presentation policy determines whether the timing of presentation is entirely managed by the framework or should only take place when the application calls
-requestInterstitialAdPresentation. By default the policy is "None", so to be
able to present an interstitial it must be changed to either "Automatic" or "Manual".

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy interstitialPresentationPolicy NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Something like:

```
self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;
```

You may need to import iAd/UIViewControlleriAdAdditions.h