# Interstitial ad waiting time

Tags: ios, iad, interstitial

So I've read that apple puts a 2-3 minute delay on ads.  But I use Words with Friends every day and it displays a full page ad every time you finish a game (and of course you can take several turns in under 1 minute).  Are they just not using iAd network?  Is there a better way to go if you need frequent ads?

I'm using 
self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;

[self requestInterstitialAdPresentation]

Comment: Do you have any source for that "claim", i have never heard of it...

Comment: I've found several people talk about it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329616/calling-interstitial-iad-works-only-one-time
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338216/requestinterstitialadpresentation-works-only-one-time?rq=1

Comment: I've also tried it and I can get one to pull up every few minutes.

Comment: okay, have not heard of it, but seems to be an occuring situation. From a users point of view I would highly advise against using full screen ads, I have not a single app one on my phone using tem, they are just f****** annoying. As soon as an app presents them, the app gets deleted - and I dont think I am the only one with that mindset ;) But back to the topic: no idea! ^^

Comment: Well scrabble does, and I don't mind them.  I just wish I knew how they did it.

Comment: Present the iAd interstitial manually. AdMob also has interstitials. https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing.  I haven't tried Admob yet though.